# Destructor with copy constructor

Tags: c++, destructor, copy-constructor

I want to use destructor in CPP, but, compiler is giving warning "undefined reference".

```
class trial{
private:
    int number;
public:
    trial(){};
    trial(int num) {
        number=num;
    };
    ~trial();
};
```

Trial class constructor gets value from main function. Help me by telling me whats incorrect in constructor. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Your destructor is not implemented. The copy ctor is fine.

Comment: Find one difference (other than `~`) between `trial(){};` and `~trial();`

Comment: There are extra `;`s at the ends of your constructors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you *declared* the destuctor `~trial();`, but you did not *define* that.

To *define* the destructor inside the class declaration, use `{}` instead of `;` like `~trial(){}`.

To *define* the destructor outside the class declaration (inside a source file), write like this:

```
trial::~trial() {
    // do what you want
}
```

Comment: or just not declare it at all